# SoX normalization and peak detection

Tags: audio, sox

I want to normalize the amplitude of sound files, and use the following:

```
sox infile.wav outfile.wav gain -n -3
```

The sound however contains peaks:

[image]

So of course, these are taken into account when the normalization is done.

Can SoX help me to detect such peaks and lower their amplitude before normalization?
(I haven't been able to find this in the documentation). Or, what would be some other recommended way to accomplish this?

Comment: It can be done using simple matlab or python script. Use the RMS value and not the max value for the normalization process